# Eclipse RCP Plugin Project top bar closed (contained View), cannot reopen it even after relaunch

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

It's my first time using the plugin development to start a project using Eclipse RCP. I started a new project, using the "Single View" template Eclipse is offering me by default. Everything worked perfectly fine and I built my own plugin based on that template. This template has a top bar  by default, with "File" as a menu on the left, and is closable.

I did not want this bar, and was wondering if I could close it. When the plugin application was launched, I press the "X" on the "File" tab on the top bar. It closed the tab, but the tab contained my whole view, so I now only had a blank screen as my plugin application.

The problem is that even if I quit the application and relaunch it, the tab is still closed (with my application view gone). I tried to clean and rebuild the project, and I tried to delete the whole project and get it again from my Git repository (I did not push any changes), but the problem persist. It seems it doesn't have anything to do with the code, but with Eclipse, as even if I change the branch on Git, it still do not show my View anymore, without changing anything in the code.

This is the code of my `Perspective` class. I tried changing the EditorAreaVisible to true, but it did not change a single thing.

```
layout.setFixed(true);
String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
layout.addStandaloneView(View.ID,  false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, editorArea);
```

In my `View` constructor, I create a frame like that:

```
java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame( swtAwtComponent );
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            pg, pd);
frame.add(splitPane);
```

The thing that I cannot understand is that it worked perfectly fine with this code, before I closed the tab in the application itself (from the graphical interface the user would use).

Would you have an idea on what I could do to get the tab again, or show my `View` in a way or another as my application, without the need to that specific tab?

Thank you very much in advance for your help. If you need any other part of my code or explanation, please let me know.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective settings are normally persisted in the workspace so the fact that the view has been closed is remembered. Normally you would use a menu option the reset the perspective but the menu option is not present in this simple RCP. So you need to set the run configuration to reset everything each time the RCP is run.

Use 'Run > Run Configurations...' to open the Run Configuration dialog. Find your RCP in the 'Eclipse Applications' section.

On the 'Arguments' tab add

```
-clean -clearPersistedState
```

to the 'Program arguments' list.

This will reset everything to the defaults each time you run the RCP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, this was driving me crazy!! ^_^